# JSON Serialization Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, json, serialization

I have this line:

```
var data = '<%=jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)%>';
```

this is the resulting data value: [image]

however , i could not use this as a json object in javascript. So , i tried

JSON.parse(data). It does not work. How can i use data as a json object?

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
                                        tabledata.setCell(i, 0, v.DateTime);
                                        alert(v.DateTime);
                                        tabledata.setCell(i, 1, v.DateTime);
                                        tabledata.setCell(i, 2, v.DateTime);
                                    });
```

And i want to use data like above codes. Can i convert data to something ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you assigning the parsed JSON to a variable? `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: yes , i assigned it. result is [object Object],[object Object]...

Comment: `JSON.parse` should work is all I'm saying. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkk7w4oe/).

Comment: I think so . but i am doing something wrong :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't something like this work, with JSON parse?

```
var data = JSON.parse('<%=jSerializer.Serialize(ObjList)%>'),
    dLen = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < dLen; i += 1) {
    console.log(data[i].DateValue + " => " + data[i].DataTime);
}
```

Comment: it gives [object Object],[object Object]... result

Comment: What about with the updated code? You should be able to access the `DateValue` and `DataTime` properties in that for loop.

Comment: The data you're parsing is an array containing a number of objects. Arrays are iterated over using a numerical index. Therefore `data[0].DateValue` is referring to the `DataValue` key/value in the first object in the array, `data[1].DateValue` is referring to the `DateValue` key/value in the second object. Because the data is being iterated over in a loop Perry can use the variable `i` to refer to the current index value, hence `data[i].DateValue`.

Comment: Hmm it is logical. Thanks for info :)